# Error consuming Web Service with Rails and Savon 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

I´m trying to consume a test SOAP Web Service with Rails 4 and Savon 2.0.

The code:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx?WSDL", 
                      log_level: :debug,
                      pretty_print_xml: true)
message = {ElementName: 'Zinc'}
response = client.call(:get_element_symbol, message)
```

The error in log:

```
Savon::UnknownOptionError (Unknown local option: :ElementName):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code is:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx?WSDL", 
                      log_level: :debug,
                      pretty_print_xml: true)
message = {'ElementName' => 'Zinc'}
response = client.call(:get_element_symbol, message: message)
```

Symbols are automatically translated to snake case in Savon 2, so instead of `ElementName` it will send `element_name`. Therefore you should use String keys instead.

Also your message should be included under `message` parameter.